# Complex and Real Representations, their differences by decomposition

Tags: representation-theory

**1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data**

Decompose $\mathbb{C}^{5}$, the 5 dimensional complex Euclidean space) into invariant subspaces irreducible with respect to the group $C_{5} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ of cyclic permutations of the basis vectors $e_{1}$ through $e_{5}$.

Hint: The group is Abelian, so all the irreps are one-dimensional. Therefore, you can use the simplified form of the projection operators, with characters.

Further, try to do the same for $\mathbb{R}^{5}$, insisting that the basis vectors can only be combined with real coefficients. What is the difference between real and complex reps?

**2. Relevant equations**

This may be the right projection operator, unsure:
$$P^{\alpha}=\frac{d_{\alpha}}{|G|} \sum_{g} \chi^{(\alpha)}(g)*O_{g}$$

**3. The attempt at a solution**

I am confused by the term decompose, so my attempts have been floundering. I tried to write out the character table for $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and I think I succeeded in that, but am unsure if it is needed. The hint about the projection operators served to confuse me more, although I readily understand the part about 1D irreps and Abelian. Is this asking me to construct reps (matrices) using cyclic permutations of $C_{5}$? If so, how am I supposed to use projection operators in this case to get them; This seems right however.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: The "decompose" part is asking you to write $V=\mathbb{C}^5$ as $V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_5$ where the $V_i$ are subspaces of $V$ that are fixed by the action of the group, i.e. for all $v \in V_i$ and all $g \in \mathbb{Z}/5$ you have $gv \in V_i$.  Each of those supspaces is one-dimensional of course, so you are really looking for five non-zero vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_5$ such that $gv_i$ is a scalar multiple of $v_i$.

Comment: The character table _will_ help you, because it tells you how this group acts on its one-dimensional reps.  Let $g$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  Then if $V_1=\langle v_1 \rangle$ has character $\chi$, you'll have $gv_1 = \chi(g)v_1$.  You know how $g$ acts on every vector in $V$ because you know how it acts on the basis $\{e_i\}$.  So to find $v_1$, write it as a linear combination of $e_i$s, and solve the equation $gv_1 = \chi(g)v_1$.  Then repeat with a different character....

Comment: I TeXified your post and attempted to recover the numbering by "hard-coding" the numbers. If something went wrong, I apologize. Please check that it looks all right.

Comment: For complex case you can just use the projections. In the real case you need to combine "conjugate" projections. As a hint I disclose that you should find a 2-dimensional real subspace, where the given generator acts by a 72-degree rotation, and another 2-dimensional real subspace, where the same generator acts by a 144-degree rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator of your group acts via the linear transformation
$T:\mathbb{C}^5\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^5, (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\mapsto(x_5,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$.
Write
$\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$. Then the vector 
$$\vec{u}_j=(1,\zeta^{4j},\zeta^{3j},\zeta^{2j},\zeta^{j})$$
is an eigenvector belonging to the eigenvalue $\zeta^j$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4$. 
Therefore they each generate an invariant 1-dimensional (complex) subspace as described in mt_'s comments. [Edit] They can also be gotten by applying the projection operators
$$
P^{-j}=\frac15\sum_{k=0}^5\chi_j^*(g^k)T^k
$$
to the vector $(5,0,0,0,0)$. Here $\chi_j$ is the character $\chi_j(g^k)=\zeta^{jk}$ for all $k=0,1,2,3,4$ and $g$ is the generator of the group.[/Edit]

The real case requires a bit more work. Observe that
$\zeta$ and $\zeta^4$ as well as $\zeta^2$ and $\zeta^3$ are complex conjugates of each other.
Thus the complex vector spaces $U_1=\mathbb{C}\vec{u}_1\oplus\mathbb{C}\vec{u}_4$ and 
$U_1=\mathbb{C}\vec{u}_2\oplus\mathbb{C}\vec{u}_3$
are stable under componentwise complex conjugation, because componentwise complex conjugation simply swaps the eigenvectors. It follows that the real vector spaces
$$
V_1=U_1\cap \mathbb{R}^5\qquad\text{and}\qquad V_2=U_2\cap \mathbb{R}^5
$$
are 2-dimensional (they are the eigenspaces belonging to eigenvalue 1 of the componentwise
complex conjugation acting on $U_1$ and $U_2$ respectively), and also stable under the action of $T$. A calculation (see also answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145405/11619), in particular the link to Keith Conrad's lecture notes) shows that the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis (over the reals) $\{\vec{u}_1+\vec{u}_4, i(\vec{u}_1-\vec{u}_4)\}$ of $V_1$ is the familiar rotation matrix. Therefore $T$ must act on $U_1$ as a rotation by 72 degrees.

Similarly the restriction of $T$ on $V_2$ is a rotation by 144 degrees.

A rotation of a real plane does not have any invariant subspaces, so we cannot refine the direct sum decomposition
$$
\mathbb{R}^5=\langle(1,1,1,1,1)\rangle\oplus V_1\oplus V_2
$$
any further. Here $(1,1,1,1,1)=\vec{u}_0$.