# Why is a matrix $A\in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ with $|\operatorname{tr}(A)|<2$ conjugate to a matrix of the following form?

Tags: linear-algebra

The trace $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ of a matrix $A$ is the sum of its diagonal entries.  Apparently if $A\in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $|\operatorname{tr}(A)|<2$, then $A$ is conjugate in $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ to a matrix of the form

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right).$$

Why is this?  I seem to have forgotten my linear algebra.

Comment: Neat question! I don't ever remember learning such a thing in linear algebra. Is there any indication that it generalizes, or does it seem to be a special quirk of SL(2,R)?

Comment: Well, I came across this in the context of Fuchsian groups, which are subgroups of $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.  I don't know of a generalisation.

Comment: There's probably some material on this in the more technical books on modular forms: Miyake, Rankin, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check theorem 3.1 from this document: [Decomposing $SL_2(R)$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,R%29.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, that's a very helpful reference.

Answer (score 7):

When we assume that $|tr(A)|<2$ for some $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, then the roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$
0=\det(A-tI_2)=t^2-tr(A) t+\det A=t^2-tr(A) t+1
$$
are complex conjugates of each other, and hence on the unit circle, so of the form $e^{\pm i\theta}$. This already implies that $A$ would be conjugate to that rotation matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. To show that they are conjugate also in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ requires a bit more.

Comment: It is pointless to attempt to top a link to Keith Conrad's notes:-). I'm afraid I couldn't easily find the correct basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Must come from the eigenvectors somehow, but I don't see it now.

Comment: It turned out that the first idea:1) pick an eigenvector $V=(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$,2)  write $V^*=(z_1^*,z_2^*)$, 3) take their "real combinations" $(V+V^*)$ and $i(V-V^*)$, and 4) write the matrix of $A$ w.r.t. this basis, does work after all. I just fumbled the calculation on my first attempt somehow.

Comment: Right, that's the approach in Keith Conrad's notes.  It's annoying when you think something doesn't work because of a calculating error!